# Tags between <echo> and </echo> in ant

Tags: ant

I have an Ant script like this:

```
<target name="create_report_file">
  <echo file="${testResultsDir}/test_report.xml">
    <testsuite name="${platformTask}">
    </testsuite>
  </echo>
</target>
```

What do the tags between <echo> and </echo> mean? Will Ant run them or output? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file is an [echo parameter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html).  It's the file to write the message to.

testsuite is possibly a JUnit task.

The Ant target runs the test suite and outputs the results to the test_report.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Ant script work? What about if it attempts to execute the `create_report_file` target?

Usually, echo tasks simply echo the contents to either the console or to a file if the `file` parameter is specified.

However, as written, it makes `<testsuite>` is a sub-entity of the `<echo/>` task, and it's not. In fact, there's no documented sub-entities in the `<echo/>` task. In fact, `<echo>` doesn't even take `<condition/>` sub-entity tasks like `<fail/>` would.

This is why I'm asking whether or not your build file is even working.

It appears they might want to log the testsuite being executed. There are two ways to do this to make this work:

#### Change all < and > to character entities:

```
<target name="create_report_file">
    &lt;echo file="${testResultsDir}/test_report.xml"&gt;
        &lt;testsuite name="${platformTask}"&gt;
        &lt;/testsuite&gt;
    </echo>
</target>
```

#### Use `<echoxml>` instead of `<echo>`:

```
<target name="create_report_file">
    <echoxml file="${testResultsDir}/test_report.xml">
        <testsuite name="${platformTask}">
        </testsuite>
    </echoxml>
</target>
```

#### Another possibility

It is possible that you're using some Ant plugin that has a `<testsuite>` task. I don't know what this would be. The `<testsuite>` task isn't part of JUnit or TestNG. However, if there is an Ant plugin being used that defines a `<testsuite>` task, it might redefine the `<echo>` task which it's at it. Does your build script have a `<taskdef>` in it? If so, what's the class reference?

It could be that the user defines their own `<testsuite>` macro in your build script. However, that wouldn't redefine the `<echo>` task and it still wouldn't work.